# How to display month name in different columns in sql using datediff function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @month INT
SET @month=1

SELECT 

    CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_Id,

    NoOfInv = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) <= @month
                        AND DATEPART(yyyy, in_date_issued) = 2014
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),

    MonthTotal = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) <= @month 
                           AND DATEPART(yyyy, in_date_issued) = 2014
                          THEN in_total ELSE 0 END),

    Grandtotal = SUM(in_total),

    RemainingAmount = SUM(in_total) - SUM(CASE 
                          WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) <= @month 
                          THEN in_total ELSE 0 END)


FROM (SELECT 
          DISTINCT MasterOrderId, cl_Id 
      FROM 
          CLOI_ClientOrderItems) as CLOI_ClientOrderItems 

INNER JOIN 
      IN_Invoices 
ON
      IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
GROUP BY 
      CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
```

i want output like

```
noofinv |amt      |clid       | grandtotal |    jan         |feb     |march  |remainingamt
5   |7.00     |100000_Pri | 245.00     |      0.00      |238.00  |7.00   |238.00
12  |2510.12  |100001_pro | 181110.29  |    138891.92   |9708.25 |510.12 |178600.17
```

If I pass month number like 3, it should display it as like Jan Feb and March and its related records in the respective month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where condition is useful for you.

```
 select Datename(mm,in_date_issued) from IN_Invoices Where Datediff(yyyy,in_date_issued,3) = 2014 and Datediff(mm,in_date_issued,@monthParameter) <= 3
```

Comment: Datename(mm,@paramMonth)

Comment: select in_date_issued from IN_Invoices Where Datediff(yyyy,in_date_issued,3) = 2014
and Datename(mm,in_date_issued) <= 3 i written like this but its not showing

Comment: any one can help me for thatquery

Comment: Ans modified, now try

Comment: giving errror "The datediff function requires 3 argument(s)."

Comment: Can you share how you want ur output?

Comment: noofinv amt      clid            grandtotal     jan              feb            march   remainingamt
5 7.00 100000_Pri 245.00          0.00          238.00          7.00 238.00
12 2510.12 100001_pro 181110.29 138891.92 39708.25 2510.12 178600.17

Comment: Pls put this output in you question, edit your que. how u can put this in comment?

Comment: i have added output see

Comment: hey friend, you have copy and pasted string, pls share output in tablular format

Comment: So, as per my understanding, if you pass 1 you want Jan as Column. If you pass 3 then you cant Jan,Feb & March as column,If 5 Then Jan,Feb,March,April,May. Correct?

Comment: yes correct same thing iwant with respective month records

Comment: Try this,http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54336/11. It is giving error in SQL Fiddle, but working fine on my SQL Server. Pls copy it on ur SQL Server & then try to understand ans. CONCEPT - you need to use Dynamic Pivot for this.

Comment: i am not getting properly pls help me

Answer (score 0):

You can Try like This...

```
 declare @MonthCount int=1
 SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, @MonthCount-1 , 
CAST('2014-01-01' AS datetime))) as Month_Name
```

OP:

```
Month_Name
January
```

Comment: i want to display month name in diff column...column namelike jan,feb,march like tat

Comment: replygor that query pls