# How to add month name in different columns in sql?

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @month INT
SET @month=1

SELECT 

    CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_Id,

    NoOfInv = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) <= @month
                        AND DATEPART(yyyy, in_date_issued) = 2014
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),

    MonthTotal = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) <= @month 
                           AND DATEPART(yyyy, in_date_issued) = 2014
                          THEN in_total ELSE 0 END),

    Grandtotal = SUM(in_total),

    RemainingAmount = SUM(in_total) - SUM(CASE 
                          WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) <= @month 
                          THEN in_total ELSE 0 END)


FROM (SELECT 
          DISTINCT MasterOrderId, cl_Id 
      FROM 
          CLOI_ClientOrderItems) as CLOI_ClientOrderItems 

INNER JOIN 
      IN_Invoices 
ON
      IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
GROUP BY 
      CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
```

If I pass month number like 3, it should display it as like Jan Feb and March and its related records in the respective month.
sql

output i want like that:

```
noofinv    amt    clid         grandtotal      jan        feb       march   remainingamt 
5          7.00   100000_Pri      245.00         0.00     238.00      7.00      238.00 
12      2510.12   100001_pro   181110.29    138891.92   39708.25   2510.12   178600.17
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display month name in different columns in sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704247/how-to-display-month-name-in-different-columns-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say display?
This is a query that returns values that are not of type date at all - so where the month should get int?

In the DB the date is being stored as a binary object - so migrating a date to be shown as text is different then running calculations on a date.
you can use DATENAME for that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx

DATEPART - just allows you to take out parts of the date. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Was I close to answer what you asked?

---

If I understand correctly - you want to create a dynamic query, that will execute and return results.
So the first part - change your query to be a string, not a query in your code.

```
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT prev_col ,'
```

Now - concatenate the columns you want in a loop

```
DECLARE @i AS SMALLINT
SET @i=1;
WHILE (@i <= month)
BEGIN
  @SQLQuery = SQLQuery + 'RemainingAmount = SUM(in_total) - SUM(CASE '+
                          'WHEN DATEPART(mm, in_date_issued) = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@month)+ 
                          'THEN in_total ELSE 0 END) AS ' + 
                          DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, @month, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime)))
                          +', ';
  @i=@i+1;
END
@SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' .... col >'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@month) + ' AS remaining'
@SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' from ..... where .....';
```

afterwards - just execute it:

```
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery);
```

again - I don't have a machine to debug it - and make it pretty... 
but I think it should be enough for you to get the idea...

Comment: i have date column in IN_Invoices table from that i find the dates and disply the month name in different columns withrespective record of the month

Comment: It is not in the query presented... Can you post the full query, with the full definition of the input parameters? or at least a full query with valid syntax - I can run on my machine and try to make sure I am answering your question?

If you are displaying the data within your application - it is not related at all to the query, it is the programming language that decides how to show it...

Comment: whatever i put thatis the full query

Comment: see i declare @month here i am passing number like 3 so now its taking all previous month means jan feb and march and calculating displying in one column of all 3 month but i want to display out like if i pass 3 means it calculate previous month and shown it in diff column like jan feb march record superatly

Comment: So you want the number of results columns to change based on the number that is being given, dynamically?

Comment: Would the <= change to = in that case ?

Comment: i have posted output see i want like that